# Mysql procedure giving error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 
  myProcedure( id INT )
BEGIN  
SELECT * FROM `board`;
END
```

//check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: In which client did you enter this? If in the command line, did you remember to set the statement delimiter to something other than ; before?

Comment: any other client i have to write this.

Comment: @AnkitAranya: I have answered the same in your previous question. Check that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

**Way 1**:

When there is only one executable statement in the procedure body, using `BEGIN` - `END` is optional. And when used, you have to use custom `DELIMITER`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure( id INT )
  SELECT * FROM `board`;
```

**Way 2**:

Define custom `DELIMITER`, define procedure, and then reset the delimiter.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myProcedure //

CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure( id INT )
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM `board`;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this solves the error

```
Delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE 
    myProcedure( id INT )
BEGIN  
SELECT * FROM board;
END 
//
```

Comment: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: Having backticks around table name or other identifiers is not an error. And semicolon is a must in MySQL. Your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

use `delimeter`

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE 
  myProcedure( id INT )
BEGIN  
SELECT * FROM `board`;
END //
```

Comment: Having backticks around table name or other identifiers is not an error. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Ravinder Now its fine??